# What is the effect of using transction type as Bean instead of Container in hibernate for timeout issue?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

we are using hibernate framework and we running one batch job.earlier our deployment descriptor file ejb-jar.xml contains `<transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>` and i got timeout exception like below...

```
javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout: causedby: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException:  ; nested exception is: javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout
```

But now i advised by my seniors like put `<transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>` instead of old one.
Now my batch job working fine...

But i dont know what is effect of changing `<transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>` here?

Could you please tell me how Transaction type Bean resolving my timeout issue?

What is the usage scenario of both Container and Bean ?

Please guide me to get clear idea about these two types...

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please tell me how Transaction type Bean resolving my timeout issue?

When the transaction is managed by the Container, the transaction boundaries (by default) is demarcated for the ejb business method, this means that all your database operations execute in the same transaction.

If you change the transaction type from Container to Bean, the Container doesn't create a new one, this allow you to manually (programatically) create and demarcate the transaction.

As you say that you only have changed the configuration file, I think that the problem was solved because simply your code doesn't execute within a transaction. If there is not transaction there is not timeout.

I don't know the details of you  batch job.earlier operation, but take in mind  that change this attribute without analize the consecuencies of executing it without a transaction can generate inconsistent data if your job.earlier operation cancels due to an unexpected error.

What is the usage scenario of both Container and Bean ?

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncih.html) you can read about it.